# AngularJS dynamic required attribute in directive and form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a directive that receives whether an element should be **required or not from a REST api**. Right now, I can't seem to get the form to invalidate when an attribute is set to required.

So, in essence I'm able to dynamically add the 'required' attribute from the directive below, but it doesn't invalidate the form. Looking through chrome I see that, even though the required attribute exists, a required entry in the $error array doesn't  exist.

```
app.directive('requireiftrue', function ($compile) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }

            if(attrs.requireiftrue==="true"){
                console.log('should require');
                el.attr('required', true);
                $compile(el.contents())(scope);
            }
            else{
                console.log('should not require');   
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/olingern/zsrfe513/) to illustrate the problem. And, here's sample JSON returned from my rest API

```
{
    race: false,
    martialStatus: true,
}
```

**EDIT:** While the accepted answer got me up and running, I still had a good bit of finagling to do.

Namely:
1. Resolving a deferred promise to ensure that my form actually receives the required fields to validate
2. observing my 'requireiftrue' attribute

**My solution**

module config:

```
function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('testState', {
        url: '/test/form',
        controller: 'TestCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'test/form/testForm.tpl.html',
        resolve: {
            formDefaultService: function getFormDefaults($q, dataservice) {
                // Set up a promise to return
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var myData = dataservice.getFormDefaults();
                deferred.resolve(myData);

                return deferred.promise;
                //return 
            }
        },

        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Test Info'
        }
    });
}
```

And, finally the directive / HTML that receives api data:

**Directive:**

```
.directive('requireiftrue', function ($compile) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }
            attrs.$observe('requireiftrue', function(value){ 
                if(value==="true"){
                    el.attr('required', true);
                    el.removeAttr('requireiftrue');
                    $compile(el[0])(scope);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input max="40"
requireiftrue={{defaults.validation.name}}
validNumber
id="name"
name="name"
type="text"
ng-model="test.name"
class="form-control">
```

Comment: Have you tried `ng-required` with expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't get it to work. When the page loads the rest call isn't finished, and doesn't evaluate the return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had two issues:
The first is el.contents() returned an empty array. so The first thing you should do is change it to el[0]. But had el.contents() worked you would hav had a much more serious problem. You would have been trying to compile a directive that has itself as a directive which would lead to an infinite loop (well until the browser crashed any way).
So here is the revised code:

```
var app = angular.module('form-example', []);

app.directive('requireiftrue', function ($compile) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }

            if(attrs.requireiftrue==="true"){
                console.log('should require');
                el.attr('required', true);
                el.removeAttr('requireiftrue');
                $compile(el[0])(scope);
            }
            else{
                console.log('should not require');   
            }
        }
    };
});
```

I should note however that now this directive is a one-off. If the model will change, the directive will not be on the element any longer to deal with it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a directive, use `ng-init` to initialize `requireiftrue`.
and assign this value to `ng-required` like `ng-required="requireiftrue"` as shown below. As you said you are getting the data from rest api, you can initialize `requireiftrue` with the value you are getting from api, instead of true or false as shown in example below.

Hope this helps you.

Updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zsrfe513/3/

```
<form ng-app="form-example" name='fo' class="row form-horizontal" novalidate>
<div class="control-group" ng-form="testReq">
    <h3>Form invalid: {{testReq.$invalid}}</h3>
 <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
 <div class="controls" ng-init='requireiftrue = true'>
   <input id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email"  name='ip' ng-required='requireiftrue'>

    <span ng-show="testReq.ip.$dirty && testReq.ip.$error.required">
        Required.
    </span>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Dont just add 'required' attribute. it always behaves like 'required=true'. If you do so, there wont be any difference between 'requireiftrue= true' and 'requireiftrue=false' which you are getting from api. It will always invalidate irrespective of 'requireiftrue=true' or 'requireiftrue=false'.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. adding the `required` directive to the input you want to apply validation to

```
<input id="inputEmail" class="requireiftrue" placeholder="Email" 
    ng-model="email" requireiftrue="true" required>
```

2 Defining the directive as type `class` and adding the directive class to the HTML input field

JS

```
app.directive('requireiftrue', function ($compile) {
   return {
    restrict: 'C',
    require: '?ngModel',
    .....
```

HTML

```
<input id="inputEmail" class="requireiftrue" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" requireiftrue="true" required>
```

here is a update of your **fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/4fb6wg30/

Comment: Hmmm, the reason I wanted the 'requireiftrue' directive was to conditionally include the 'required' attribute on the input

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the "required" attribute to the input.

```
<input max="40"
requireiftrue={{defaults.validation.name}}
validNumber
id="name"
name="name"
type="text"
ng-model="test.name"
class="form-control"
required="required">
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `<input ng-required="true">` worked fine for my angular validation component.

If your using the new angular component make sure to pass in required: "@" instead of required: "="

```
scope: {
      required: '@'
    }
```

I also took this further and required integer and min/max validation the same way.