# Angular dynamic required validation of group of fields with field highlight if invalid

Tags: angularjs, validation, dynamic, required, subform

UPDATE 1: the question will be enhanced based on the feedback from the comments.
UPDATE 2: Some progress has been made. Need additinoal help to get through. Please read below.
UPDATE 3: Bug fixing in provided sample code causing duplication in table rows when compiling the element using `$compile(el[0])(scope);`.

On page load, a list of field names is retrieved from Database which indicates what fields are required using ajax call `getRequiredFieldInfo()`. This call must be completed successfully before executing the related angular code under the directive `check-if-required` to manipulate the `required` attribute. This directive must loop over all input fields and mark them as required based on the list which is retrieved from the Database.

I did some research and found this post which seems to be the closest to my requirements:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28207652/4180447

and finally found a working jsfiddle version here (updated):

http://jsfiddle.net/tarekahf/d50tr99u/

I can use the following simple approach:

```
<input name="firstName" type="text" foo ng-required="isFieldRequired('firstName')" />
```

The function `isFieldRequired()` will check if the passed field name is found in the list, it will return true.

The problem with this approach is that I have to add this function to each and every field which might be required.

Also, will have to pass the field name each time. To be more efficient, I will have to use a directive on the parent element `div` or `fieldset` which will allow me to access all child elements, and process the required attributes for the all the input elements.

This directive need to be changed as follows:

- To be added to the parent element of the group of fields whose `required` attribute will be processed and modified if needed.
- Compare the element name against the list of fields to set as required and apply the change accordingly.

The updated code (as I am researching the solution):

**STYLE**

```
input.ng-invalid, li.ng-invalid {
    background:#F84072;
    border: 2px red solid;
}
```

**HTML - NAVIGATION TABS:**

```
<ul  class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.homeForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}" class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home"><%=homeTabName%></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.clientForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1"><%=clientTabName%></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.appraiserForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}"> <a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2"><%=appraiserTabName%></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.propertyForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3"><%=propertyTabName%></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.serviceForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu4"><%=servicesTabName%></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.constructionStage.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu5"><%=constructionStageTabName%></a></li>    
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.costForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu6"><%=costTabName%></a></li>  
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.certificationForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}" ng-click="redrawCanvas()"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu7"><%=certificationTabName%></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.photosForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu8"><%=photoTabName%></a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'ng-invalid':mainForm.mapForm.$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu9"><%=locationTabName%></a></li>    
</ul>
```

**HTML - Form**

```
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade" ng-form="appraiserForm">
    <fieldset ng-disabled="isAppraiserSigned()" check-if-required>
        <input type="text" id="appraiser_name" name="appraiser_name" ng-model="sigRoles.appraiser.roleNameModel" style="width: 536px; ">
        <input type="text" id="appraiser_company" style="width: 536px; ">
        ... 
        ... 
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Javascrip:**

```
app.controller('formMainController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q', function($scope, $timeout, $q) {

    $scope.runProcessAndInit = function () {
        var q = $q.defer();     //Create a promise controller
        angular.element(document).ready(function(){
            //perform all client updates here
            q.resolve('success');   //notify execution is completed successfully - inside document 'ready' event.
        })
    return q.promise;   //return the promise object.
    }
    //mainPromiseResolved is used to indicate all ajax calls and client updates are done.
    $scope.mainPromiseResolved = false;
    $scope.mainPromise = $scope.runProcessAndInit();
    $scope.mainPromise.then(function(success) {
        //debugger;
        $scope.$broadcast('event:force-model-update');
        //mainPromiseResolved is mainly used in angular validation to prevent showing errors until all client updates are done.
        $scope.mainPromiseResolved = true;
        return 'main promise done';
    })
    $scope.isFieldRequired = function (prmFieldName) {
        var isFound = false;
        var oRequiredField = formView.getRequiredField();
        findField: {
            for(var subformName in oRequiredField) {
                isFound = prmFieldName in oRequiredField[subformName];
                if (isFound) {
                    break findField;
                }
            }
        }
        return isFound;
    }    
    function getRequiredFieldInfo() {
        var q = $q.defer();
        var appUrl = getAppURL();   
        $.get(appUrl + "/servlet/..."
                    + "&timestamp="     + new Date().getTime(), 
                    function(data, status){
            //console.log("json fields:" + data);           
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            formView.setRequiredField(obj);
            q.resolve('success');
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(formView.getRequiredField()));            
        });
        return q.promise;
    }
    $scope.requiredFieldsPromise = getRequiredFieldInfo(); 
}]);

app.directive('checkIfRequired', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) {
                //return;
            }
            //debugger;
            var children = $(":input", el);
            angular.element(document).ready(function (){
                scope.requiredFieldsPromise.then(function(success) {
                    //remove the attribute to avoid recursive calls
                    el.removeAttr('check-if-required');
                    //Comment line below as it caused duplication in table raws, and I don't know why.
                    //$compile(el[0])(scope);
                    angular.forEach(children, function(value, key) {
                        //debugger;
                        if (scope.isFieldRequired(value.id)) {
                            angular.element(value).attr('required', true);
                            //el.removeAttr('check-if-required');
                            $compile(value)(scope);
                        }
                    });
                })
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

I've already made some progress. However, I still need more help. Following is the status:

- Done: get required fields list from DB and then execute code in directive to manipulate the `required` attribute.
- Done: Loop over the child input elements from a given angular element `el` which is passed to link function `function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel)`.
- Done: Add `required` attribute to each child element if `isFieldRequired(fieldName)` is true?
- Done: Use promise to ensure all ajax DB calls and client updates are done before executing angular code.
- How to recursively loop over the child elements if they are nested inside another `ng-form` subform or `div` element?
- How to ensure that each element has ngModel object?
- How to restrict the directive to `div`, `fieldsset` or similar elements?

Tarek

Comment: I'm lazy so rather than adding a directive to every input I would be personally inclined to only add one to the form or fieldset and  query the elements by field name vs name attribute and set required as applicable. Then call $apply() once when done and wouldn't need to use `$compile`

Comment: Thanks a lot @charlietfl ! I think I understand what you mean, however, I still need more help. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will satisfy the main requirement, in addition, for each element under the `div` block, it will allow adding attribute `check-if-required-expr`. This new attribute may be used to call a scope boolean expression to decide the `required` attribute in case the field is not found the list of required fields.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the standard `ng-required` directive instead of the custom attribute `check-if-required-expr` which basically does the same as `ng-required`. The only problem if I use `ng-required` is that it might override the logic of the required field if it was specified in the list.

So the question here: is there a way to find out if the `required` attribute is set, and if yes, then do not check the required expression, otherwise, execute the `ng-required` expression.

### HTML

```
<div id='signature-pad' class="m-signature-pad break" ng-class="{'ng-invalid':certificationForm[theRoleData.signatureBase64].$invalid && mainPromiseResolved}" check-if-required>
...
    <div class="m-signature-pad--body">
        <canvas id="appraiser_signature_section" redraw ng-signature-pad="signature" ng-hide="isSigned()">
        </canvas>
        <img ng-src="{{signatureDataURL()}}" ng-hide="!isSigned()" load-signature-image>
        <input id="{{theRoleData.signatureBase64}}" name="{{theRoleData.signatureBase64}}" type="text" ng-hide="true" ng-model="signatureBase64" check-if-required-expr="sigDetailsAvail(theRoleData)" force-model-update/>
    </div>
...

</div>
```

Basically, in the above HTML, the `input` field which has `check-if-required-expr`, indicates that if this field is not found in the `list of required fields` then execute the expression to decide if the field is required.

### JavaScript

```
//Define directive check-if-required
//This directive will loop over all child input elements and add the required attributes if needed
app.directive('checkIfRequired', ['$compile', '$timeout', '$parse', function ($compile, $timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        /*require: '?ngModel',*/
        require: '?^form',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngForm) {
            /*if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }*/
            var saveIsValidationRequired;
            var children;
            saveIsValidationRequired = scope.isValidationRequired;  //Save current flag value
            scope.stopExecValidations();
            el.removeAttr('check-if-required');
            $timeout(function() {
                //Get all input elements of the descendants of `el` 
                children = $(":input", el);
                //Run the following as early as possible but just wait (using promise) until 
                //  the list of required fields is retrieved from Database
                //scope.requiredFieldsPromise.then(function(success) {
                scope.requiredFieldsPromise.then(function(success) {
                    //The line below caused duplication of the table in construction stage, so it is removed and no impact
                    //$compile(el[0])(scope);
                    angular.forEach(children, function(child, key) {
                        var elmScope;
                        var elmModel;
                        try {
                            if(child && child.id) {
                                elmScope = angular.element(child).scope() || scope;
                                elmModel = angular.element(child).controller('ngModel');
                                if (ngForm && elmModel && ngForm[elmModel.$name]) {
                                    scope.$watch(function(){
                                        //Watch the errors for the defined field - convert to JSON string.
                                        return JSON.stringify(ngForm[elmModel.$name].$error);
                                    }, function (newValue, oldValue){
                                        //The validation error message will be placed on the element 'title' attribute which will be the field 'tooltip'. 
                                        var maxlength;
                                        var minlength;
                                        if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
                                            if (ngForm[elmModel.$name].$error.maxlength) {
                                                //If invalid, add the error message if number of entered characters is more than the defined maximum
                                                maxlength = scope.$eval(angular.element(child).attr('ng-maxlength'));
                                                child.title = ("Number of characters entered should not exceed '{0}' characters.").format(maxlength);
                                            } else {
                                                //Remove the error if valid.
                                                child.removeAttribute('title');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                if (scope.isFieldRequired(child.id)) {
                                    angular.element(child).attr('ng-required', "true");
                                    $compile(child)(elmScope);
                                }
                                //Check if the element is not in "Required" list, and it has an expression to control requried, then
                                //... add the attribute 'ng-required' with the expression specified to the element and compile.
                                if (!angular.element(child).prop('required') && child.attributes.hasOwnProperty("check-if-required-expr")) {
                                    var isRequiredExpr = child.attributes["check-if-required-expr"].child;
                                    angular.element(child).attr('ng-required', isRequiredExpr);
                                    $compile(child)(elmScope);
                                }
                                var validObjects = scope.getFieldValidation(child.id);
                                if (angular.isArray(validObjects)) {
                                    for (var idx=0; idx < validObjects.length; idx++) {
                                        var validObject = validObjects[idx];
                                        var test = validObject.test || "true"; //if not exist, it means the rule should always be applied
                                        var minLenExp = validObject.minlen;
                                        var maxLenExp = validObject.maxlen;
                                        var isRequiredExp = validObject.required || false;
                                        isRequiredExp = angular.isString(isRequiredExp)?isRequiredExp:isRequiredExp.toString();
                                        //scope.$evalAsync(function(){
                                            if (test && (minLenExp || maxLenExp || isRequiredExp)) {
                                                var testEval = scope.$eval(test, elmScope);
                                                if (testEval) {
                                                    if (minLenExp) {
                                                        angular.element(child).attr('ng-minlength', minLenExp);
                                                    }
                                                    if (maxLenExp) {
                                                        angular.element(child).attr('ng-maxlength', maxLenExp);
                                                    }
                                                    //If the "required" expression is '*skip*' then simply skip.
                                                    //If '*skip*' is used, this means the required validation is already defined in code
                                                    //and no need to replace it.
                                                    if (isRequiredExp && isRequiredExp != '*skip*') {
                                                        angular.element(child).attr('ng-required', isRequiredExp);
                                                    }
                                                    //Change how '$compile()' is used.
                                                    //      After reserach, found there is bug in Angular which is causing the fillowing issues when using '$compile()':
                                                    //      1. Duplicate values for drop-down list items.
                                                    //      2. Inteference with dateppciker Angular UI Bootstrap control
                                                    //      If this still happes, more research is needed to resolve this problem.
                                                    //      This is still work-in-progress. More research is needed.
                                                    //The compile statement below will be replaced ...
                                                    $compile(child)(elmScope, function (clone) {
                                                        angular.element(child).after(clone);     
                                                        angular.element(child).remove();
                                                    });
                                                    //Apply only the first matching validation rule
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.error("Error occuured in 'checkIfRequired' directive while applying validation logic on element ID '%s'. Error is: '%s'", child.id, e);
                        }
                    });
                    //If saved flag value is ture, enable validation
                    if (saveIsValidationRequired) {
                        scope.startExecValidations();
                    }
                });
            });
            //})
        }
    };
}]);
```